# how to add string var in array

Tags: php, wordpress

here's my function i'd like to replace :
    array('administrator','author') with a var like array($string)
So i have an array from my theme options (from a select field), which return the user role i need in my function, it returns like this :

```
 Array ( [0] => administrator [1] => author [2] => subscriber )
```

I did :

```
 $string = "'".implode("','",$array)."'";
```

my function:

```
add_filter("login_redirect", "subscriber_login_redirect", 10, 3);

function subscriber_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user) {

    if(is_array($user->roles))
      if ( count( array_diff( $user->roles, array($string) ) ) !== count( $user->roles ) ) return site_url('/wp-admin/')

    return home_url();
}
```

But still issue,in my consolelog, the string var returns 'administrator','author', 'subscriber'

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use explode to create an array out of a string

```
Array ( [0] => administrator [1] => author [2] => subscriber )

$string = implode(",",$array);

add_filter("login_redirect", "subscriber_login_redirect", 10, 3);

function subscriber_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user) {

    if(is_array($user->roles))
      if ( count( array_diff( $user->roles, explode(",",$string) ) ) !== count( $user->roles ) ) return site_url('/wp-admin/')

    return home_url();
}
```

The "," may not be a good delimitter, use something that will most likely be unique like a pipe | or maybe even a stringcombination (like !|! for example)

Comment: great thanks, i use pipe. info about [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)